# how do i setup a trigger after all inserts are done with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, triggers

here is a trigger that i have setup:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tbl_dt2()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
    $tbl_dt$
        BEGIN
            IF NEW.first_date IS NOT NULL THEN
                NEW.first_date:= TO_DATE(NEW.first_date,'DD-MON-YY');
            END IF;
            IF NEW.second_date IS NOT NULL THEN
                NEW.second_date := TO_DATE(NEW.second_date ,'DD-MON-YY');
            END IF;
            RETURN NEW;
        END
    $tbl_dt$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER t_tbl_dt2
    AFTER UPDATE ON csv_tbl
    FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION f_tbl_dt2()
;
```

basically, it's just changing the date format.

thing is, it doesn't seem to work unless i change the trigger to execute PER ROW - instead of after the entire insert is done as per the python below (where df is just a pandas dataframe):

```
df.to_sql('csv_tble', if_exists='append', con=engine, method='multi')
```

i'd like some advice, my goal is to first insert all the rows in the pandas dataframe, and then, after it's entirely populated to run the update trigger.  otherwise, i believe it would take longer.

Comment: You are correct you would need a row level trigger, statement level triggers do not have access to new/old pseudo rows. However you have a much larger misconception. When stored **there is no such thing as a date format**,dates  are always stored in an internal stucture.  Whether the original input format is 'DD-MON-YY', 'MM-DD-YYYY', 'yyyy-mm-dd' they are* all stored identically*. If you want a specific format you must specify what is wanted when the column is selected.

Comment: @Belayer you lost me on a couple things here...1) is there a way to know when that to_sql function is done, on the server side? 2) is there a way to create a trigger that will fire after that happens, and update the table's columns? 3) the table that is being populated has all columns as strings..so a bit confused by what ur talking about with the dates... thank you!

Comment: 1) It should be `AFTER INSERT` as `multi` does inserts. 2) `to_date()` converts a string to a `date`: `select pg_typeof(to_date('03/16/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY')); date` which contradicts your assertion that the columns are strings. If the `first_date` and `second_date` are coming in as strings then don't do the `to_date`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver im a bit dense here.  all the columns come in as strings ('04-MAY-22').  reason i'm trying to convert to date is so that i can filter out the ones that are most recent (since the sort doesnt work on this string format).  i dont want to change the date format for the entire database.  So, i'm just converting the strings into date.  the table columns themselves are 'text'.  thanks for taking the time

Comment: 1) I repeat, your trigger is `AFTER UPDATE` and will not fire as `multi` does inserts. 2) If the columns are `text`, then this `TO_DATE(NEW.second_date ,'DD-MON-YY')` is going to end up as text in the database: `select pg_typeof(to_date('18-MAR-22', 'DD-MM-YY')::text); text`. So you end up with the date in the column as a string in whatever the server format for a date is. If you want to work with dates then make the columns `date` type.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the issue was originally that when i tried to insert the data, it wouldn't accept it into a date formatted column - and i didnt want to adjust the data client-side. so, i opted to imported it as a string, and then try to fire a trigger after the import.  so you're saying, even though i update individual cells - the column data type is still a date...the thing is the sorting works in that way.  so i'm not sure why it matters?

Comment: You need to provide the schema definition for `csv_tbl`. I don't how else to explain it, the imports are being done as `INSERT`s and your trigger is for `UPDATE`'s so it will not fire after the import. Also if as you said earlier the columns are all text then the data will be store as text not `date`s.